# How to call a class public method while initializing an attribute in dataclass in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I just learned about data classes in Python and I am super stoked to try and use them. In the process, I am trying out an example where, I would like to call a class method to initialize one of the class attributes. Here is an example of what I am trying:

```py
@dataclass(init=True, repr=True, eq=True, order=False, unsafe_hash=False, frozen=False)
class Test:
    def connect_to_database(self):
        string = f"DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={self.server};" \
                                   f"DATABASE={self.database};Trusted_Connection=yes;"

        return pyodbc.connect(string)

    server: str = field(repr=True, default='my_server')
    database: str = field(repr=True, default='my_database')
    conn: str = connect_to_database() # This fails - cannot reference self in dataclass ?
```

As I read around, one of the options I found recommends using the post_init(), seems like a good suggestion, however I would like to know if that is the option, does that allow overloading? I have a different use case in mind for post_init(). Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just use a property?

Comment: @wim, Can you please provide a working example ?

Comment: Not until I understand what the question actually is.  So, why not just use a property?  Note that at the time of class definition, you don't have *any* instances (the type doesn't exist yet) - so what were you expecting the `test_method()` to actually do?

Comment: What part of the question do you not understand? Please provide helpful feedback  if you plan on helping

Comment: This is the part that I do not understand: you say that `c: float = test_method()` fails, but what are you even trying to do there?  This method does not return anything, so even if it *didn't* fail, what would you expect it to actually do? Set the default value of `c` to `None`?

Comment: @wim, 
      'c' is an example. The intent I am trying to convey is if I need to use an attribute that I have assigned and use it in a class method, how can I achieve that. For e.g.: 
Let us replace the class definition with something more meaningful(updating in original post due to limit)

Comment: A dataclass with a connection to a database as a field?  I don't think that's a great idea.  Dataclasses are supposed to be simple bags of data, not handling complicated stuff like db connections, which usually need transaction management, context, rollback etc.

Comment: Your question description no longer describes the nature of the code represented. Using dataclass to represent data returned from a db query is one thing but handling db connections is another that’s what clients are for

Comment: And using a "class to represent data returned from a db query" is a well-traveled domain already, it's usually called a "model" (google for "ORM")

Comment: Python never allows for overloading, so no. post_init is one way to do this, but as stated above, it sounds like you probably shouldn't use a data class here, if you attributes are going to requrie all this, OR pass your attributes fully initialized to the constructor. Then it is a true data class, basically a class used mostly as a container of fields.